# How to create a Sitecore Framework Plugin-based project in Visual Studio

Tags: identity-server

The instructions for configuring a sub-provider for the Sitecore Identity Server (https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/use-the-sitecore-identity-server-as-a-federation-gateway.html) tell you to create a Sitecore Framework Plugin-based project in Visual Studio. Where can I find the source for this project template or further instructions as to how to create this type of project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sitecore Support responded to a ticket I opened with this question. They outlined three steps for creating the project.

1. Create a new Class Library project
2. Add a reference to [Sitecore.Framework.Runtime.Build](https://sitecore.myget.org/feed/sc-identity/package/nuget/Sitecore.Framework.Runtime.Build). Set the attribute `PrivateAssets` to All.
3. Add references to other dependencies as needed:

   - Add Sitecore.Framework.Runtime.Commands to enable commands in your plugin
   - Add Sitecore.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions to enable using runtime abstractions in your plugin
   - Add references to other plugins if you build on features already in a plugin

I also think the information on creating [Sitecore Host Plugins](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/sitecore-host.html) is applicable.